# Is there a similar function to C# Select() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#

I am new to Javascript and I was wondering is there a similar function in Javascript like C# Select(). My task is from array of people to sort the age of them and select only age of each person and print it. And this is what i come up with:

```
ageArraySorted = args.sort(function(person1, person2) {
    return person1.age - person2.age;
});
```

I sorted them and now I need only the values of age property to be printed.

Answer (score 6):

Without a library like `linq.js` the closest analog is the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap) method on `Array`;

```
ageArraySorted = args.sort(function(person1, person2) {
  return person1.age - person2.age;
}).map(function(item) {
  return item.age;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

be careful with Map as a new to javascript

map does not mutate the array on which it is called (although callback, if invoked, may do so).

```
var numbers = [1, 4, 9];
var roots = numbers.map(Math.sqrt);
// roots is now [1, 2, 3]
// numbers is still [1, 4, 9]
```

and map was added to the ECMA-262 standard in the 5th edition;

Feature     Chrome  Firefox (Gecko)     Internet Explorer   Opera   Safari
Basic support   (Yes)   1.5 (1.8)   9   (Yes)   (Yes)

from ...https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: `Select` doesn't mutate arrays either...